# Can I delete this partition?

Tags: windows-xp, hard-drive, partitioning, windows-vista

I have an HP Laptop that came with an OEM version of windows vista. I have set it up to dual boot with windows XP. Therefore there are 2 primary partitions. There is also one more primary partition Labeled HP_RECOVERY.

This all makes sense, except there is one more *Primary* partition labeled as Local Disk. It is 214 MB and says 171 MB used, however, when i open it, even showing hidden files, there appears to be nothing on the disk.

So now I want to add one more primary partition, but I am unable to since there are already 4. Can I delete the extra "Local Disk" partition to make another one?

Thank You,
Blaine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually  small percentage of the partitions  available space is used to store file system-related data but it wont be shown if you try to view  with show  the hidden files.This is for applied for all partitions.I have also had small partitions with 100 mb labelled as primary with the same used space so i have format it and added with another disk make sure it is not system reserved partition.

Comment: so you think that this is actually empty and I would be safe deleting it?

Comment: Yes,Deleting the empty partitions wont cause any problem  may sure it is not system reserved partitions

Comment: ok, thank you. I don't think it is system reserved

Comment: Ok, I ended up just turning it into a logical partition just in case. But it allowed me to create another primary partition, so all is well! using the 3rd OS now. Thank you once again.

Answer (score 0):

Windows can put a small paritition (usually 100MB) before your regular partition. It is highly likely that this is what you are refering to. This is used for stuff like bitlocker.

In that case your bootloader could be on this partition. Therefore it is highly recommended NOT to delete that partition. Since removing the bootloader means your OS will no longer start. This can be fixed but it takes a bit of effort.

Given that you have two choices:

1) Just create an extended partition (why not, right?)

2) remove the HP recovery partition*

*These are hidden EISA, but it is not hard to unlock them using Diskpart.